# Failed Docker AWS Code Build error: Reason: exit status 125

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build a docker container in AWS code build as a means to deploy a container to ECR, but I get this error.

Comment: This probably means the `docker run` command failed. More information is required to help.